# Append a slugyfied field based on unique id to an URL in Django

Tags: django, url, url-rewriting, django-urls

Someone inputs `www.example.com/3/`

I have a model with a charfield that I can slugify.

```
class Mymodel(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

How can I rewrite the url as `www.example.com/3/title-of-selected-id` in Django?

Do I do it in the urls.py or in the views.py? All I could think of was making 2 patterns like this

```
(r'^mymodels/(?P<mymodel_id>\d+)/(?P<name_slug>[\w-]+)$', 'app.views.detail'),
(r'^mymodels/(?P<mymodel_id>\d+)/$', 'app.views.rewrite'),
```

And then in my app.views.rewrite I would get the mymodel title, slugify it and redirect to the first url. But this seems awfully dirty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through #django irc someone told me that the redirect method wasn't bad, and we couldn't think of another easy way so I just coded something up which seems to be working.

```
#urls.py
(r'^mymodels/(?P<mymodel_id>\d+)/$', 'app.views.detail'),
(r'^mymodels/(?P<mymodel_id>\d+)/(?P<name_slug>[\w-]+)/$', 'app.views.detail'),

#views.py
def detail(request, mymodel_id, name_slug=None):
    mymodel = get_object_or_404(Mymodel, pk=mymodel_id)

    slug = slugify(mymodel.title)

    if slug == name_slug:
        return HttpResponse("model number %s." % mymodel_id)
    else:
        return redirect(reverse('app.views.detail', args=[mymodel_id, slug]), permanent=True)
```